# Phonegap Build Blackberry Error starting: Module attempts to access a secure api

Tags: blackberry, code-signing, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, phonegap-build

My wife and I are currently working on a Phonegap Build app for distribution in BlackBerry World; however, whenever we try to run the app on a BlackBerry, we get the message "Error starting [TheApp]: Module ‘[TheApp]’ attempts to access a secure api."

We know that there are a lot of questions out there about this particular error and even some that pertain to Phonegap, but there don't seem to be any that answer the question from a Phonegap Build perspective or solve our particular problem.  The most common answer seems to be that the application has not been signed or has not been signed properly, but this should not be case as we successfully uploaded out sigtool.csk and sigtool.db files to Phonegap Build and no error was raised when building for BlackBerry.  Also the local installation of the 3 code signing files (RBB, RCR, RRT) that we did through the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin in order to obtain sigtool.csk and sigtool.db was successful.  There are also a lot of answers out there pointing to the incompatibility of JDK 1.7 and Signature Tool, but we are using JDK 1.6 JRE 6, so this should not be the problem either.  We also thought of requesting signing keys with access to the secure element from BlackBerry, but those keys seem to be for NFC only, and the app we made doesn't use any NFC, unless Phonegap Build causes it to call some NFC api for some reason.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  We are using Phonegap v2.7.0 in Phonegap Build.